# Setting proxy in c++ app on visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, proxy, visual-studio-2005

Can someone help me in setting proxy via `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE devenv.exe.config`. I changed `</system.net>` and added `defaultProxy`. I closed visual studio 2005 and opened again and built but that did not work.

Background:
I have an issue with one of C++ app which uses 3rd part API to connect to source and fetch realtime feed. Infra team has introduced a proxy and this is not allowing us to connect to source as earlier. We tried bypass list via netsh but that also did not work.

Comment: please show a [mre], what is trying to connect and how is it doing so? changing the visual studio config is unlikely to have an effect unless it's visual studio itself trying to connect to something

Comment: Thanks Alan for your reply. We are trying to connect to source using google:protobuf API connection = pCommModule->Connect(&queueIn); without proxy we were able to connect. with proxy settings we receive - not able to connect error. so , i am trying to set the application with the proxy URL. any other way to indicate the proxy for app will also help.

Comment: Please edit a [mre] into your question